# Swagger in Net 4.5.1 existing project

Tags: c#, asp.net, swagger

I have an existing project that contains a number of APIs. I would like to do a documentation of these APIs. While searching I came across Swagger which seems not bad. So I installed the nugets packages (Swashbuckle.Net45 -Version 5.2.1). I configured SwaggerConfig and started my project. When I go to the URL localhost [port_num] / swagger I have the following error:

> "ExceptionMessage":"Not supported by Swagger 2.0: Multiple operations with path 'api/Pdf' and method 'GET'.

I do not really understand what this error is so if someone has already had this and has a solution I am a taker.

Answer (score 1):

Swagger has a stricter rule set for the naming / routing of your controller methods.

The error suggests that you have multiple methods on a controller that are mapped via the same Http Method and path.

Check for any methods in your controllers that match api/Path and change one of them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Indeed I missed [HttpGet] on some API.